# How to read csv file in Java and convert the column as key and row-value as value pairs

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a CSV input file `sample.csv`:

```
Student_name   Roll_num   Marks 
Anvay          1001         80
Vini           1002         69
Jay            1003         70
```

How can I read the data line by line in Java 8 using OpenCSV and parse it as list of key value pairs? (keeping key as column_name & value as row-value)?

**Expected output**:

```
['Student_name': 'Anvay', 'Roll_num': 1001, 'Marks':80]
['Student_name': 'Vini', 'Roll_num': 1002, 'Marks':69]
['Student_name': 'Jay', 'Roll_num': 1003, 'Marks':70]
```

Comment: Use [CSVReaderHeaderAware](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReaderHeaderAware.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can read easily the csv file using automatic mapping.
Here a simple method to read a generic type of row:

```
   private <T> List<T> readMapped(File file, Class<T> clazz, int skipLines) {
    List<T> beans = null;
    try {
        beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(
                new FileReader(file))
                .withType(clazz).withSkipLines(skipLines)
                .withSeparator(';')
                .build()
                .parse();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        throw new MyException("cannot read csv file", e);
    }
    return beans;
}
```

Now, you can define the following data type (I use lombok, but if you don't, remove the ToString and getter/setter annotations and write the corresponding methods):

```
@ToString
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Student {
        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
        private String name;
        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
        private Integer rollNumber;
        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
        private Integer mark;
    
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
@CsvBindByName(column = "COLUMN_NAME")
```

Then, use the following call:

```
public List<Student> readStudent(File file) {
    return readMapped(file, Student.class, 1); //first row is the head, if you have put labels on the first line
}
```

That's all!

Comment: sorry, the last step is to convert Student to json (as I can understand it is the goal), it's easy, for example : https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-convert-java-object-to-json/